# Whats the meaning of "-" (minus) in PHPs ASP style tags

Tags: php, asp.net, variables, echo, interpolation

Uhh, turns out I was asking the wrong question. The tag were not PHP but rather JavaScript templating ones. Thanks again for answering to all, it were good leads to getting to the bottom of this.

---

I am trying to understand how some legacy PHP Code works. There is this code:

```
<%- variable %>
```

It renders the content of variable. So it seems to be a command similar to `<?= variable ?>`, but this command does not output the content of the variable.

I think the key is to understand, what the meaning of the "-" is. Unfortunately I haven't found an explanation for this online, since this seems to be not a very usual way to do things and I don't know much about PHP.

Comment: That's not valid PHP. It looks more like a template style.

Comment: This seems to be part of a framework.

Comment: By "legacy", how old is it? ASP-style tags were available up until 5.3 I think, then deprecated in 5.4. They've been removed in 7. But while `<%= $value %>` would have been valid, your example above doesn't look like it was ever valid PHP code. Can you show more context?

Comment: I've seen that in [ERB](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) templating.  It would be equivalent to  `<?= ltrim($variable)?>` in php.  As other comments have suggested, that isn't valid php on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far. I don't find any hints that a widespread templating tool or framework is used. The tags are within HTML content, like 
```<p>
  <% if ('' != link) { %>
    <a href="<%- link %>">
  <% } %>
  [...]
</p>```.

Comment: Is there something I can grep for to figure where this is defined?

Answer (score 0):

The tags were not PHP tags but JavaScript templating ones. I was not aware of it when asking the question.